# How to patch form values with dynamic form control names

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this form:

```
public profileSettingsGroup = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl('Jonathon', Validators.required)
})
```

I have this method:

```
setControlValue(control: string, value: string){
  this.profileSettingsGroup.patchValue({
    control: value
  });
}
```

I have this map:

```
for (let control in this.profileSettingsGroup.controls) {
  this.map.set(control, this.camelCase(control));
}
```

I'm attempting to update the controls in the form via a variable, but angular seems to not allow me to dynamically name form controls.  It's taking `control` as an actual control named: "control".  Can I do what I want in angular?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need brackets around control. See [computed property names over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

```
setControlValue(control: string, value: string){
  this.profileSettingsGroup.patchValue({
    [control]: value
  });
}
```